# When should I use library.function() (for a given library and its function) instead of just function(), using Python Libraries

Tags: python, oop, libraries

I am very new to Python and Object Oriented Programming. I'm performing [this tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/boids-simulating-birds-flock-behavior-in-python-9fff99375118) that uses the p5 library.

The tutorial's posted code is like:

```
from p5 import setup, draw, size, background, run
import numpy as np
from boid import Boid

width = 1000
height = 1000

def setup():
    #this happens just once
    size(width, height) #instead of create_canvas

def draw():
    #this happens every time
    background(30, 30, 47)

run()
```

But when I try to run it, all sorts of errors occur unless I place "p5." before the functions `background()`, `size()`, and `run()`:

```
... p5.size()
... p5.background()
... so on
```

I have had this confusion at other similar codes; sometimes the library name was used before the function, sometimes it wasn't, so the code above is just an example to show my general ignorance on the topic.

Any explanations or directions to where I could learn about this are welcome.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
from p5 import setup, draw, size, background, run
```

The names `setup`, `draw` etc. are added to the global namespace and bound to the proper library functions/objects (i.e. those from the `p5` library)

But after that, when these lines run:

```
def setup():
...
def draw():
```

The names `setup` & `draw` are changed to point to the functions you just define, so they are not bound to the `p5` library objects anymore.

Due to the ambiguity in the names, the script might run into errors. However, your script should be okay since those re-defined names don't seem to be used anywhere.

Using the `p5.` prefix just clears up that confusion & fixes the issue.

It's always best practice the use the `library.` prefix if the library exports names that are generic like `setup`, `draw` etc. Or if the name clashes with your own names / other librarys exported names.

Comment: They are typically not methods, they are just functions or other types of objects (e.g. classes)